# Import XML of span element fails with #N/A

Tags: google-sheets-formula

finally decided to sign up to stackoverflow because of this. So I´d be super grateful about a solution!

I´m trying to get a **number** of a `<span>` element. Here is an [image of the data box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60nlo.png) I´m trying to scrape from. It´s on this page: https://de.marketscreener.com/kurs/aktie/SNOWFLAKE-INC-112440376/analystenerwartungen/

The relevant Xpath is `//*[@id="highcharts-0oywbsk-200"]/div[2]/div/span/span`

I´m trying: `=IMPORTXML("https://de.marketscreener.com/kurs/aktie/SNOWFLAKE-INC-112440376/analystenerwartungen/"),"//div[2]/div/span/span")`

I´m ignoring the @id-element, this works pretty well with many elements on the same page, but in this case not at all. I ignore the id, because I can´t use it as it changes on every page. Is this ok?

Google Sheets always gives me a #N/A error?! Any idea how to scrape that number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

disabling JavaScript reveals what you can scrape:

[image]

Comment: oh damn, i thought I had deactivated the script, but now that I´m trying again it´s true. Thank you for the response anyways!